# Exporting class template with out-of-body definitions from DLL with MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, templates, mingw, dllimport, dllexport

I am facing trouble properly linking a trivial Windows executable to a trivial DLL with MinGW-w64 (based on GCC 11.3.0 from MSYS2) when class templates are involved. A minimal reproducer is as follows.

The complete code of the library (*library.cpp*) is

```
template <class T> class __attribute__((dllexport)) TestClass
{
    public:
        void member() { __builtin_printf("member from library\n"); }
        void other_member();
};

template class __attribute__((dllexport)) TestClass<int>;

template <class T> void __attribute__((dllexport)) TestClass<T>::other_member () {}
```

and I compile it using

```
g++ -std=c++11 library.cpp -o library.dll -shared -Wl,--out-implib,library.dll.a -Wl,--output-def,library.def
```

The complete code of the program (*program.cpp*) is

```
template <class T> class __attribute__((dllimport)) TestClass
{
    public:
        void member() { __builtin_printf("member from program\n"); }
        void other_member();
};

extern template class __attribute__((dllimport)) TestClass<int>;

int main (void)
{
    TestClass<int> test;
    test.member();
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile it using

```
g++ -std=c++11 program.cpp library.dll.a -o program.exe
```

The linking of the program to the DLL fails with `undefined reference to TestClass<int>::member()`. It turns out that the linking failure can be solved in two ways:

1. The extern template statement in the *program* is commented out. Then the compiler uses the local version of the template and the program prints "member from program".
2. The definition of `TestClass<T>::other_member` is commented out from the *library*. Then the program properly links to the `TestClass<int>::member` in the library and it prints "member from library".

I understand the first point, where the extern template is avoided and a local implicit instantiation takes place. This also happens when I compile the code with optimizations.

But the second point perplexes me. Why does the out-of-body definition of `TestClass<T>::other_member` break export of `TestClass<T>::member`?

Disclaimer: I am debugging someone else's program, so the design choices are not mine.

Answer (score 2):

Template classes are usually used in header files.
They are merely definitions, which only become actual code once instantiated with an actual type.

So in that respect I don't see how this can be exported as a symbol in a DLL:

```cpp
template <class T> class __attribute__((dllexport)) TestClass
```

This does make sense, since the compiler can generate code because the type is known:

```cpp
template class __attribute__((dllexport)) TestClass<int>;
```

Here is how it would make more sense in my opinion:

**library.hpp**

```cpp
#if !defined(DLL_EXPORT_LIBRARY)
# if defined(_WIN32) && defined(BUILD_LIBRARY_DLL)
#  define DLL_EXPORT_LIBRARY __declspec(dllexport)
# elif !defined(STATIC) && !defined(BUILD_LIBRARY_STATIC)
#  define DLL_EXPORT_LIBRARY __declspec(dllimport)
# else
#  define DLL_EXPORT_LIBRARY
# endif
#endif

template <class T> class TestClass
{
    public:
        void member();
        void other_member();
};

template class DLL_EXPORT_LIBRARY TestClass<int>;

template <class T> void __attribute__((dllexport)) TestClass<T>::other_member () {}
```

**library.cpp**

```cpp
#include <library.hpp>

template <class T> void TestClass<T>::member()
{
    __builtin_printf("member from library\n");
}
```

**program.cpp**

```cpp
#include <library.hpp>

int main (void)
{
    TestClass<int> test;
    test.member();
    return 0;
}
```

build:

```sh
g++ -std=c++11 library.cpp -I. -DBUILD_LIBRARY_DLL -o library.dll -shared -Wl,--out-implib,library.dll.a -Wl,--output-def,library.def
g++ -std=c++11 program.cpp -I. library.dll.a -o program.exe
```

Comment: Refactoring the code in this way works and possibly makes more sense. But I am dealing with someone other's large code and trying to find out what is wrong about it (or with the compiler?) without rewriting the code completely. The inline definition of `member` is exported all right by MinGW-w64, but only when `other_member` is absent. Your answer does not explain this. You do seem to be correct that the dllexport/dllimport qualifier on the class template itself is redundant. But omitting it does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware:
In `library.cpp` there is no (explicit) instantiation of the class template, or the member function of said class.

```cpp
template class __attribute__((dllexport)) TestClass<int>;
```

Would be an (explicit) 'template specialization forward declaration'... (Because of course it would).
Long story short, if (and that's a bold assumption) I'm right you just need to add `{}` after `TestClass<int>` to have the type "defined".

To answer:

> Why does the out-of-body definition of TestClass::other_member break export of TestClass::member?

I'm even less confident. But why are you defining a member function of a specialization of `TestClass`?  Does it need a `template` at all?

cf: [Explicit (full) template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

Comment: I tried using `template<> class __attribute((dllexport)) TestClass<int>{};` instead of the forward declaration, but got the same error. I also tried defining `other_member` just for the `int` specialization, with no improvement either.